# how to get table columns without constraints in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

i'm creating history table associated with each master table based on following query

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO HISTORY_TABLE FROM MASTER_TABLE
```

this query creates an empty table named `HISTORY_TABLE` consisting of columns similar to columns in `MASTER_TABLE` but with constraint's that are applied to the `MASTER_TABLE`.

so is their any way to get columns without constraints?

Comment: You want to select all the columns or columns without constraints??

Comment: want to select all the columns without constraints.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be good idea, but this does what you want..

```
//This creates the table with constraints
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO HISTORY_TABLE FROM MASTER_TABLE

//This will drop all the constraints
DECLARE @database NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(255)
SET @database = 'databasename'
SET @table = 'HISTORY_TABLE'
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE constraint_catalog=@database AND table_name=@table)
BEGIN
SELECT @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @table + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE constraint_catalog=@database AND table_name=@table
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: i dont want to drop the constraints applied on the history table after table created, instead i want to create the history table from master table without any constraints..

Comment: Try this out, this does not copy keys, indexes, default contraint, but takes not null constraint.. Select TOP 0 * Into HISTORY_TABLE From MASTER_TABLE Where 1 = 2

Answer (score 0):

This gets you a table with a clean set of columns.

```
select top 0 * into #bounce from MASTER_TABLE
select * into HISTORY_TABLE from #bounce
```

But they are so clean you'll need to define the PK, indexes, etc. (but you may need those to be different on a history table anyway...)